# Deploy Sharepoint Online Intranet app

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, deployment, office-365-developer

I have developed an intranet application in SharePoint Online.
Now I want to deploy to a customer site where they will have their own SharePoint online account.

How will I deploy it into my customer's environment ?
I would also like to know how to deploy my app design into customers environment, do I need to package design seperately or I can directly use design codes (HTML/CSS) into the files while coding my application?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you do not need to move/copy files, but you need to publish your app to App catalog.
See if this helps : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164070.aspx

thanks

Comment: What about the design of the intranet?
That can also be achived by publishing app to App Catalog?

Comment: do you mean masterpages? if so check this out : http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/02/26/a-guide-to-quick-sharepoint-2013-branding/